# Disable "Phone number" field in CKEditor

Tags: dotnetnuke, ckeditor4.x

I use CKEditor for DNN version 4.11.4 with the "CKHtmlEditorProvider".

How to disable the "Phone number" field in the Link-Button in the CKEditor?

See the screenshot:

[CKEditor Phone number](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AS781.png)

It is makeable by CSS, but i search for the solution through the config.js, something like

```
   if ( dialogName === 'link' ) { 
       dialogDefinition.removeContents( 'tel' );
    }
```

Comment: I just tested on my site and I don't get the phone number option on my install, running DNN 9.3.1 at the moment. What version are you on?

Comment: I have: 

`DNN PLATFORM v. 09.02.02`

`4.6 .NET FRAMEWORK`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "Phone number" field was only a mistake in the programm. 
The dnnckeditor plugin owner has corrected it now: 
https://github.com/w8tcha/dnnckeditor/issues/60

Answer (score 0):

What CKeditor are you using? I use DNNConnect.CKE and that has no link to phone either.
If you go to http://yoursite.com/Host/HTMLEditorManager I can verify that in the editor config tab and search for linktype.

Comment: You mean which CKEditor provider I use? I use CKHtmlEditorProvider, not the DNNConnect.CKE.
CKEditor for DNN version: 4.11.4.

Comment: In that case I recommend to switch to the DNNConnect version. This is also the HTML editor that is the default in any new DNN9 install